# Ios popToRootViewControllerAnimated causing Memory Issues

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, sprite-kit

I am making my SpriteKit game. When the player dies, my goal is to have the game transition back to the start screen. This is accomplished by the code below. However, I notice that the memory increases each time a new game begins. Xcode Instruments is not showing a memory leak. When the memory reaches roughly 150mb the games frame rate drops and the game become unplayable.

In the `GameScene` I call this function when the player dies

```
func gameOver(){
    if let block = gameOverBlock {
        worldNode.removeAllChildren()
        worldNode.removeAllActions()
        worldNode.removeFromParent()
        self.removeAllChildren()
        block()
    }
}
```

Back in the GameViewController the following functions get called

```
     scene!.gameOverBlock = {
        [weak self] in
        self!.goBack()
    }
}

func goBack(){
    scene!.removeFromParent()
    navigationController!.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(false)
    return
}
```

If anyone has any ideas as to how I can accomplish this without a memory leak, it would much be appreciated.

Comment: What is `worldNode`? A SpriteKit Scene?

Comment: worldNode is just an SKNode() inside of gameScene. It holds all the game elements

Comment: I wonder if there is some sort of strong reference cycle going on. All view controllers besides the first is being deinitialized and perhaps another object is still holding the pointer to it so it never leaves memory and that would explain your ever growing memory.. Good luck these problems suck.

Answer (score 2):

After commenting out tons of code, I have found the problem. The methods that I have posted above were not causing the leak, as Matthew suggested, there was a strong reference in the middle of my code that was stopping the ARC from releasing memory. Ill post the problem code incase anyone else may have a similar problem.

In my GameViewController, I had the following block:

```
  scene!.zoomInBlock = {
       self.scene!.size = CGSizeMake(self.scene!.size.width / 2, self.scene!.size.height / 2)
    }
```

The correct way (without causing a strong reference) to write this would be:

```
  scene!.zoomInBlock = {
     [unowned self] in self.scene!.size = CGSizeMake(self.scene!.size.width / 2, self.scene!.size.height / 2)
    }
```